# How to unselect a stackpanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I have a TreeView, a root TreeViewItem - the root TreeViewItem has horizontal Stackpanel children, each of these children has a Checkbox and a TreeViewItem, this TreeViewItem has a header as a name, and it has one child, a Shape.

When the user manually clicks on the Shape, it selects the entire Stackpanel area.
I need to programmatically unselect the Stackpanl.

```
TreeView 
  TreeViewItem   
     StackPanel [[CheckBox] [TreeViewItem]
                             [System.Windows.Shapes.Shape]]
```

StackPanel doesn't have an IsSelected attribute, and neither does the Shape object.

Summary how to unselect a Stackpanel?

Comment: I think you just have to set your RoutedEvent as "Handled"

Comment: Why is there a TreeViewItem in you StackPanel?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "selects" the stack panel? Do you mean there is the dashed line adorner around it?

If so that is there because your StackPanel is focusable and the dashed line adorner is indicating what element has focus.

You can set Focusable=false on the StackPanel to prevent it from being able to receive focus.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "selected"

Comment: Well there's the highlighted blue box around it

Comment: any chance to get a screenshot? It sounds like what you mean is that the TreeViewItem is selected, which is what a TreeViewItem does since TreeView is a type of ItemsControl which has the concept of selected items